# @font-face not working in Firefox with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, firefox, font-face

My @font-face is working in all browsers except Firefox. I read somewhere that placing the IE .eot versions at the top and wrapping them in conditional tags would work but it didn't for me. Everything was working on mamp locally but when I uploaded it FF wasn't reading the font. It's a wordpress site. I tried following these suggestions but got nowhere:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-font-face-not-working-in-firefox?replies=21

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ColaborateThinRegular';
src: url("../fonts/Colaborate-fontfacekit/ColabThi-webfont.eot");
src: url("../fonts/Colaborate-fontfacekit/ColabThi-webfont.eot?#iefix") 
format("embedded-opentype"), 
url("../fonts/Colaborate-fontfacekit/ColabThi-webfont.woff") format("woff"), 
url("../fonts/Colaborate-fontfacekit/ColabThi-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), 
url("../fonts/Colaborate-fontfacekit/ColabThi-webfont.svg#ColaborateThinRegular") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

Comment: So you're using W3 Total Cache? and have you done everything suggested in that thread?

Comment: The site has been up a couple of days and suddenly the font is working in Firefox. I have no idea why, hadn't changed anything relating to the fonts since. I did disable my plugins temporarily this morning, maybe something there triggered it.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of answering this question, based on your response in the comments above i'd say your issue was caused by W3 Total Cache 'saving' a version of your page without Firefox working.

When you do frontend changes / css changes in the future make sure you hit the **"Empty All Caches"** button.

For more information make sure you check out the [W3 Total Cache documentation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) and I suggest watching the [tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=rkmrQP8S5KY) too.

If the problem comes up again (specifically in firefox) download and install the [Firebug plugin](http://getfirebug.com/) and check your page for errors etc.

Hope this helped.